# How to count rows with two values in any of the many columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have some Excel columns that look like this:

```
    A       B       C       D
1   Amy     Bob     Carol   David
2   Carol   David   David   Carol
3   Bob     Carol   Amy     Amy
4   David   Amy     David   Amy
```

I need to count the number of rows where both Amy and Bob occur, no matter which column they are in. In this example, the number should be 2 (row 1 and row 3).

I already know COUNTIFS with which I can count the number of rows with 'Amy' in column A (or any particular column), and 'Bob' in column B (or any particular column). The formula would be:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"Amy",B1:B4,"Bob")
```

However, this formula seems to require you to specify the columns. I tried to change it to

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:B4,"Amy",A1:B4,"Bob")
```

and it returned 0, which is not what I'm after. I need to count the number of rows where both Amy and Bob occur, regardless of the columns they are in. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a helper column where you check whether actual row contains both names:

`=COUNTIF (A1:D1,"Amy")*COUNTIF (A1:D1,"Bob")>0`

Then just count cells with `TRUE`:

`=COUNTIF (E:E,TRUE())`

Comment: Thanks. So if I also need to count rows with both Amy and Carol, I need another helper column? One helper column for each combination. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Thanks. Your method works except that I have to change the last COUNT to COUNTIF. Also if I have a large number of rows and columns this requires quite some effort to create all the helper columns. Is there a way where I can put a (possibly quite convoluted) formula into one cell and get the result?

Comment: Good point. That should be COUNTIF too.

Answer (score 0):

Just break it up

> =COUNTIF(A1:D1,"Amy")+COUNTIF(A1:D1,"Bob")

Alternatively, you can do it with an array function

> =SUM(COUNTIF(A1:D1,{"Amy","Bob"}))

Then you can do things like:

> =IFERROR(CHOOSE(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"Amy")+COUNTIF(A1:D1,"Bob"),"One Match","Two Matches"),"No matches")

Comment: This counts ALL occurrences of Amy and Bob, instead of the ones being in the same row.

Comment: I have the ranges restricted to a single row.

Comment: Shoot. I juuust missed the five minute edit window for my previous comment. Please disregard it.

Thanks, I fixed the typos. I had the ranges set to columns instead of rows, and I used COUNT instead of COUNTIF for one of the formulas. I also added a practical example.

Comment: Down voting over a typo is pretty harsh.

Comment: "Count the number of rows where both name occurs", "in this example the number should be 2". It's not a typo,  your answer is not an answer to this question.